# Who was the character that appeared at the end of the movie?

Tags: character, star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, what appeared to be Darth Maul appeared in a hologram.  Does anyone know if that was actually Darth Maul, or was it another Sith that looked exactly like him?  If it was him, wouldn't that screw up the timeline, as Maul was killed when Anakin was 8-ish, but would have been alive when Solo was in his early 30s?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is the former Sith, Maul.

Many people whom have only ever watched the films do not realize that Darth Maul survived after *The Phantom Menace* and where he reappears in the TV series, The [Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Wars), and turns up again in the TV series, *Star Wars Rebels*, which *Rebels* takes place after *Solo: A Star Wars Story* and both of those works (*Solo & Rebels*) takes place inbetween *Revenge of the Sith* and *A New Hope*.

> At the end of Solo: A Star Wars story, it's revealed Emilia Clarke's
>  Qi'ra **has been in contact with fan favorite Star Wars villain, Darth
>  Maul, played once again by Ray Park**. If you've only followed the Star
>  Wars movies, your last memory of Darth Maul was seeing him fall to his
>  apparent death after being sliced in two by Obi-Wan Kenobi at the end
>  of Episode I: The Phantom Menace.
>
>
>  However, if you've watched the Star Wars: The Clone Wars series, you'd
>  know **Darth Maul survived his fight with Obi-Wan. You'd also know he
>  now has robotic metal legs.** We have an even more in-depth explanation
>  on where Maul has been and what it means for future Star Wars movies
>  here. Actor Sam Witwer is voicing Maul in Solo, who also provided the
>  character's voice on The Clone Wars show. (FYI on the timeline, which
>  can admittedly get confusing: The Clone Wars series takes place
>  between Episode 2: Attack of the Clones and Episode 3: Revenge of the
>  Sith. Solo: A Star Wars Story takes place some time after Episode 3,
>  but before Episode 4: A New
>  Hope.)

https://www.cnet.com/news/that-solo-a-star-wars-story-cameo-explained-qira-clone-wars-rebels-best-part/

---

[HERE](https://www.cbr.com/solo-star-wars-story-rebels-timeline-explained/2/) is a breakdown of the timeline.

> By this point the old Jedi Master is in self-imposed exile on
>   Tattooine. This is where the revenge driven Sith finally falls. Season
>   3 of Rebels takes place in 2 BBY. So, if you’ve been doing the math,
>   Solo is 10 years after The Clone Wars: Season 4, 9 years after Revenge
>   of Sith, and 8 years before Rebels: Season 3.

Comment: Also just to clarify: Han Solo is 19 & 22 in Solo: A Star Wars Story (there is a time jump in the film)

Comment: Wait.  My Star Wars is rusty, but wasn't Maul cut in half in The Phantom Menace??

Comment: @JohnnyBones yes, but he survived and recieved cybernetic legs.
Please click on Clone Wars link provided or go to Wookiepedia and look up Darth Maul. The character has been around in other Star Wars materials, as explained in answer.

Comment: Literally no one ever could survive being cut in half and falling hundreds of feet into a shaft, and then lay there unaided for perhaps hours or days.  And if one COULD survive, due to some technology advancement, then said advancement would allow for sewing his lower half back on.  After all, his legs and pelvis would be lying nearby...

It's a stupid plot twist that makes no sense.  (Why not re-grow Anakin's arms and legs like a salamander while we are at it?)

Comment: And if Darth Maul could survive THAT, then why not pluck Boba Fett out of Sarlac? He was merely slowly digesting in a creature likely damaged or killed in the assault on Jabba's Sail Barge.  The notion of the Fett climbing out of Sarlac seems much less far-fetched.