# Age portrayal of Han Solo

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the end/climax of ***Solo: A Star Wars Story***, it is shown that Qi'ra is conversing with Darth Maul. If I recall properly, Darth Maul was cast in the ***Episode I: The Phantom Menace***. It was the time when Anakin Skywalker was a youngling. His master, friend, and brother Obi Wan Kenobi killed Darth Maul in the climax of *The Phantom Menace* after the fall of the latter's master Qui-Gon. Then how come is he present in the times of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*? Is Han Solo quite older compared to Luke And Leia? I am having serious confusion thinking of the timeline.

Comment: Harrison Ford was born around 10 years before Mark Hammill and 14 years before Carrie Fisher.  Han definitely acts older and more worldly wise than Luke.

Comment: Yeah, I know their real age differences, but I wasn't aware of the age differences in the story-line of Star Wars. And I didn't even think much about it when I was watching the originals, because Harrison Ford looked so freaking handsome (I just fell in love with his face and his acting) that the age difference wasn't quite knowingly visible, or might be I am not a good judge of age.

Comment: @iandotkelly obligatory "how can luke and leia be twins if they are 4 years apart" ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Han Solo starts *['Solo'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Solo#:%7E:text=A%20film%20featuring%20Han%20Solo,orphan%20on%20the%20planet%20Corellia.)* at age 19, and then the story jumps ahead three years when Han is 22 years of age.

> Solo: A Star Wars Story
>
> Alden Ehrenreich portrayed a younger Han Solo in Solo: A Star Wars
> Story. Main article: Solo: A Star Wars Story A film featuring Han Solo
> before the events of the 1977 film was released on May 25, 2018,
> starring Alden Ehrenreich. **In the film, 19-year old Han is
> characterized to be an orphan on the planet Corellia**. He and his
> lover, Qi'ra (Emilia Clarke), attempt to escape from a criminal gang
> and bribe an Imperial officer with a stolen sample of coaxium, a
> powerful hyperspace fuel, in exchange for passage on an outgoing
> transport, but Qi'ra is apprehended before she can board. Han vows to
> return for her and joins the Imperial Navy as a flight cadet. He is
> given the surname "Solo" by the recruiting officer, apparently
> referencing Han's statement that he "has no people".
>
> **Three years later**, Han has been expelled from the Imperial Flight
> Academy for insubordination.

[image: Maul]

In addition Darth Maul survives being cut in half by Obi-Wan in *The Phantom Menace*, becoming just "Maul" continuing his story on in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, and eventually dying in *Star Wars: Rebels*.

By the time of 'Solo', Maul has become the leader of [Crimson Dawn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Crimson_Dawn), which is solidified at the end of the film.

Yes, Han Solo is about a decade older than Luke & Leia Skywalker.

For the full time line between the Prequels and OT, please see my answer with source on this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89445/who-was-the-character-that-appeared-at-the-end-of-the-movie).

Comment: If I am not wrong Clone Wars and Rebels are animation series which are spin-offs. Yeah I haven't watched them yet. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, but both are canon! :)

Comment: True, that is...

Answer (score 5):

According to **Solo: The Official Guide**, Han Solo is stated to have been born in 32 BBY. He is somewhere between 19 and 22 in the movie.

As for Darth Maul, if you watch the credits, he is credited only as **Maul**, no Darth anymore, he is not a Sith Lord anymore, he had been replaced by Darth Vader. And it seems that you don't follow spin-off materials, Maul has a long run in these, he rebranded himself as a crime lord, and if you look carefully he has robotic spider legs.

Comment: If by spin-offs, you are referring to Clone Wars, then I must say I didn't watch that. And yeah I didn't notice he has robotic legs, because it quite wasn't visible in Solo movie. Thanks!